# Python-Turning a string into and integer while keeping leading zeros

Tags: python, string, integer

I am trying to convert a string, such as 'AB0001', to an integer that appears as '001'

I am trying:

```
x='AB0001'
z=int(x[2:len(x)])
```

though my output is:

```
1
```

I need this to be an integer to be used in:

```
format_string=r'/home/me/Desktop/File/AB'+r'%05s'+r'.txt' % z
```

Thank you for your time and please let me know how to acquire the following outcome:

```
format_string=r'/home/me/Desktop/File/AB0001.txt'
```

Comment: Why does it need to be an integer?

Comment: Integers do not have leading zeroes. I think what you're looking for is to format into a string with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have leading zeros at all in python3 and in python 2 they signify `octal` numbers. If you are going to pass it into a string just keep it as a string.

If you want to pad with 0's you can zfill:

```
print(x[2:].zfill(5))
```

I don't see why you slice at all thought when you seem to want the exact same output as the original string.

```
 format_string=r'/home/me/Desktop/File/{}.txt'.format(x)
```

will give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're going to be using the `int` in a string, correct?  Since this is the case, you should do exactly what you're doing:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> format_string = r'/home/me/Desktop/File/AB%04d.txt' % x
>>> print(format_string)
/home/me/Desktop/File/AB0001.txt
>>>
```

You don't need to store the variable as an `int` with the format `001` (which you can't do anyway).  You convert it to that format when you create `format_string`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [string-formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string-formatting) via the `.format()` method is good for this.

```
x='AB0001'
resulting_int_value =int(x[2:])  # omitting the last index of a slice operation will automatically assign the end of the string as the index

resulting_string = r'/home/me/Desktop/File/AB{:04}.txt'.format(resulting_int_value)
```

Results in:

```
'/home/me/Desktop/File/AB0001.txt'
```

Here, `{:04}` is a format specifier telling string to format the given value by filling with up to 4 leading zeros.

Therefore,　using `"{:04}".format(0)` will result in the string, `"0000"`.